# How to create custom option that is common to all products

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, transactional, shopping-cart, dropdown-attribute

There is a dropdown list on product detail page,
That can be select-able by the user,

After the user selects an option from dropdown list and after he adds this product to the cart,

this selected option should be displayed in cart as well as checkout page,
and also displayed on transaction emails.

How can I achieve this ?

As I am new to magento, please a hint will also be helpful to me,...

Comment: Add a new attribute in admin panel. because attributes are attached to the products. You can create a dropdown attribute easily. please go to `Catalog` -> `Attibutes` -> `Manage attributes` and then click on `Add new attribute`. and then follow instructions to create a dropdown attribute. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green, This attribute won't be available on cart page and checkout-page or transnational-emails, That is the main problem.

Comment: I never worked on the pages you mentioned above but if you have access to a product (_atleast id_) then you can access its related attributes.

Comment: ^ That's right. On any pages where you have products, the product models are available and you can fetch any data they have if the default page doesn't already display it.

Comment: But, Are you sure, that user-selected dropdown option attribute will be available  on checkout or cart page ?
I am trying it, but its not showing it to the cart page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, I think, would be to implement custom options, `Catalog` -> `Manage Products` -> product page -> `Custom Options` tab, if you're looking to add options that is "common to all products." These will show on your order pages, cart, checkout, etc. by default. I don't know about transactional emails, but I'm sure you can if you want to.

I'll need more information to give you a more detailed answer.

The suggestion by `Mr_Green` also works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked for single product,
Is there any way set custom product for all products from configuration or anywhere ? Atleast common for category !!

Comment: LuFFy, so the custom options need to be assigned for every single product separately, unfortunately. However, there are ways to do what you want; an extension or a Magento shell script (`Magento_Shell`) will do what you want. Are you familiar with any of these (shell script is much easier, IMO)?